# -[CCFileUtils fullPathForFilename:resolutionType:] : cocos2d: Warning: File not found:

Tags: ios, objective-c, menu, cocos2d-iphone, texturepacker

-[CCFileUtils fullPathForFilename:resolutionType:] : cocos2d: Warning: File not found:  play.png

Cocos2d game....extremely simple just started it.

This is the entire class and the "play.png" and "sound.png" are not being found. They are both located in "buttons.plist" (texture packer documents) and are included in the Build Phases.

Class:

```
- (id) init {

    if ((self = [super init])) 
    {
    //[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"looped.mp3" loop:YES];
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"buttons.plist"];

        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        CCSprite* background;
        if( winSize.width == 568 || winSize.height == 568 )
            background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"title_bg-5x.png"];
        else
            background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"title_bg.png"];

        [background setPosition: ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2)];
        [self addChild: background];

        CCMenuItemImage *play = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"play.png" selectedImage:@"play.png"
                                                                   target:self selector:@selector(actionGame:)];


        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            play.position =  ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
        }
        else
        {
            play.position =  ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
        }

        CCMenuItemImage *sound = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"sound.png"
                                               selectedImage: @"sound.png"
                                                      target: self
                                                    selector:@selector(actionSound:)];
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            sound.position=ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
        }
        else
        {
            sound.position=ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
        }


        CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:play, menu, nil];
        [self addChild:menu z:4];

    }


    return self;
}
```

Navigator:
[image: the .plist files with "play.png" and "sound.png"]

Build Phases has all the .plist files and .png files too.

Any ideas why I am getting this error / why the buttons are not showing up? This is just the start of the project and I've never had this issue before.

Thank you for any help you can provide me.

Comment: these menu item initializers don't look for sprite frames in a texture atlas. To use a sprite frame use the menu item initializer that takes an existing sprite as input, and create that sprite with a sprite frame from the atlas

Comment: I cannot find what you mean; CCMenuItemSprite?

Comment: I tried         CCSprite *test = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"play.png"];
        
        CCMenuItemSprite *play = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:test selectedSprite:test target:self selector:@selector(actionGame:)];
but the error said: reason: 'child already added. It can't be added again'

Comment: you can't use the same sprite for normal and selected, i think

Comment: It can't even find the images from the sprite sheet for some reason? -[CCFileUtils fullPathForFilename:resolutionType:] : cocos2d: Warning: File not found:  (even when I change the selected)

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen on first initialisation or after?

If it happens after the first:

Check if you used;

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
```

Somewhere after the init. Same problem occurred on my project as well and I think that the code above doesn't work as I expected.